# confusion: Flames program using simple logic

Tags: java

Hi friends im learning java from basics..
I have written flames program on my own and i got struck on some poit, please help me.

**MY CODE**

```
import java.util.*;


class Solution
 {
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    int i,j,count=0;
    String f ="FLAMES";
    char[] fl = f.toCharArray();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.nextLine();
    String s2 = sc.nextLine();

    for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<s2.length();j++)
        {
         if(s1.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(j))
         {
             count+=1;
             break;
         }
        }
    }
    int x=(s1.length()+s2.length())-(count*2);
    for(i=0;i<=x;i++)
    {
        */need logic here/*

    }
    System.out.print(fl);

   }
  }
```

I have counted number of unmatched letters in both string.
now i have to find and print the match for the count ex: F or A or M

**Note**

i read many program examples but there are using totally different.

i need to remove the elements in the "FLAMES" string and display the remaining one.

PLEASE Help me....

Comment: *now i have to find and print the match for the count ex: F or A or M* In what way are F, A or M an example of finding and printing a match for a count?

Comment: Ex: if count is 6, in first hydration i need to delete S, In second hydration i need to delete F, In 3rd A and so on... at last the remaining one letter i have to print.

Comment: Could you put some sample input and output that you're expecting? I'm not sure what the question is, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I also did the flames program in the same way what you did...just check mine and yours understand the logic I used...check with some names and if you don't understand don't hesitate to ask me...

```
import java.util.*;
public class Flames
{
     public static void main()
     {
        int sp=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter two names");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        String s1=sc.nextLine();
        String p="flames";
        String p1="flames";
        String s2="";
        String m="";
        for(int i=0;i < s.length();i++)
        {
           if(s.charAt(i)==' ') 
           {
           }
           else
           {
              m=m+s.charAt(i);
           } 
        }
        s=m;
        m="";
        for(int i=0;i < s1.length();i++)
        {
           if(s1.charAt(i)==' ')
           {
           }
           else
           {
              m=m+s1.charAt(i);
           }
        }
        s1=m;
        m="";
        int l=s.length();
        int l1=s1.length();
        for(int i=0;i < l;i++)
        {
           int sl=0;
           for(int j=0;j < s1.length();j++)
           {
               if(s.charAt(i)==s1.charAt(j))
               {
                  if(sl==0)
                  {
                     sl++;sp++;s2=s2+" " ;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     s2=s2+s1.charAt(j);
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                    s2=s2+s1.charAt(j);
                }
             }
             s1=s2;
             s2="";
         }
         sp=sp*2;
         int c=(l-1)+(l1-1)-(sp-1);
         for(int i=1;;i++)
         {
            String z="";p=p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p;
            String mn="";
            char c1=p.charAt(c);
            for(int j=0;j < p1.length();j++)
            {
                if(c1==p1.charAt(j))
                {
                   mn=p1.substring(j+1)+mn;
                       break;
                }
                else
                {
                   mn=mn+p1.charAt(j);
                }
             }
            for(int k=0;k < p1.length();k++)
            {
                if(c1==p1.charAt(k))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                   z=z+p1.charAt(k);
                }
            }
            p1=z;
            p=mn;
            if(mn.length()==1)
            {
              System.out.println(mn);
                   break;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, you got the count i.e Unmatched count and now ,you have to iterate over the letters flames and delete each one, until one is remaining, which is the required relationship between two people.

Now, think of a 12 hour time. When someone say the time 16, you interpret as 4. Why, because you are checking the number in a 0 - 12 range. You add the excess from the beginning i.e 0.

16 = (16÷12) gives 4.

There are total of 6 letters in flames. Range of 0-5 index.
Once the letter removed, its comes to range of 0-4.
Finally, It comes to one.

So let us consider the count of 17.

**First step:**

17 in the range of 5.
startIndex = 0
17 ÷ 5 gives 2.

2nd index is A. so remove A.
nd start from M in

> FLMES

. Now M is 2.

**Second step:**

Range:4
startIndex = 2
(2+17) ÷ 4  = (19÷4) = 3 . Now remove 3rd index E.

> FLMS

**Third step:**

Range:3
startIndex = 3
(3+17)÷3 = 2. remove 2nd index.

> FLS

**Fourth step:**

Range:2
startIndex = 2.
(2 + 17) ÷ 2 = 1. remove 1st index letter.

> FS

**Fifth step:**

Range:1
startIndex = 1
(1 + 17) ÷ 1 = 0.
Remove 0 th index letter F remaining with 'F'

> F is the answer

```
start
startIndex = 0
Iterate over  5 i.e beginning range
starIndex  = ( startIndex + count) ÷ range;
remove letter at starIndex.
end
```

Better to store flames in list, which will take care of removal and reordering of index.

**Note:**

Unmatched count is the sum of difference in count of each alphabet in both the words.

```
unMatchedCount = abs( count[a] in firstWord - count[a] in secondWord)
                  + abs( count[b] in firstWord - count[b] in secondWord)
                  ..............
                  + .............. till z.
```

So Its better the calculate the counts using hashing for better performance.